# c++ и KOI8 (setlocale)

Tags: c, c++

Привет всем. Нужно открыть файл, который закодирован KOI8-R.
Пробовал

```
#include<locale.h>
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.KOI8-R");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.KOI8R");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.koi8-r");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru-RU.koi8-r");
//и тд
```

Ни один из вариантов не работает, все возвращают NULL.
Нужно кросс платформенное решение, т.е. чтобы код компилировался и на Linux, и на Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнение про setlocale() и KOI-8.

В винде проходит вызов setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian_Russia.20866"); для установки КОИ8.

См. ПанельУправления->ЯзыкиРегиональныеСтандарты->Дополнительно [Кодовые страницы таблиц преобразования].

```
// char *pl = setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian_Russia.20866"); // koi8-r
// char *pl = setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian_Russia.65001"); // utf-8
// char *pl = setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian_Russia.1251"); // cp-1251
// char *pl = setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian_Russia.28595"); // iso8859-5
char *pl = setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian_Russia.866"); // cp-866
```

Comment: А в линуксе возможно 1251 выставить? А то у меня что-то [не получается](https://tio.run/##Rcy7CoNAEEbhfp7ixzQKSdBAKi8Q0lrlBWQZB1nQUZzdKuTZNwGLVAdO8fG2XSbmlE5eeY6joJlXdrN09D9@tbCLWzqiaF4nqFvENscCC2NN5DVgcV7zgt4E8BoDmga5STi0vH8Oj74/I3tFM@90OHqtbvcqK9C2KIsfBOwS4q4oa/qk9AU).

Comment: @Qwertiy, наверняка можно. Но проще прямо в меню терминала. У меня в **gnome-terminal** в пункте меню `Terminal`->`Set Character Encoding`->`Cyrillic -- WINDOWS-1251`. И работать в программе в  однобайтной кодировке. А вот setlocale на практике я не юзаю почти вообще

Answer (score 0):

Вариант:

Используем для конвертации [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx). В качестве параметра должен стоять "koi8-u" за нумером 21866 или "koi8-r" (20866). При этом в системе должен стоять соответствующий nls-файл.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю это только под винду, проблема в том, что я решаю задачу и отправляю на онлайн тестирование, там естественно стоит линукс и код может не компилироваться. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Плюс я бы попробовал <a href=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/codecvt_byname/>std::codecvt</a> и производные. Хотя есть подозрение, что под виндой он так же не будет работать :-(

Comment: Поправил пост. Думаете std::codecvt под винду не будет работать, а под линукс наоборот?

Comment: Не понял насчет #ifdef'ов, обрамить setlocale или std::codecvt, чтобы только под виндой работало или под линуксом?

Comment: <pre>// считали данные в бинарном виде
#ifdef WINDOWS_BLA_BLA_BLA
// конвертируем с помощью MultiByteToWideChar
#elif LINUX_BLA_BLA_BLA
// используем setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.KOI8-R");
// и пр. стандартные ф-ции.
#endif</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/): сначала грузить как двоичный файл, затем преобразовывать из одной кодировки в другую, например, из KOI8-R в UTF-8.

Comment: К сожалению, никакие дополнительные библиотеки нельзя использовать, только STL

Answer (score 0):

Такой локали может и не быть в системе.
А кто мешает просто открыть файл в бинарном виде и прочитать содержимое?
Для этого никакая локаль не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

В винде вообще непросто. В файлах одна кодировка (ее можно узнать по setlocale(LC_ALL,"")),
в консоли другая (обычно cp-866, но может быть настроена cp-1251 и даже, говорят, UTF-8 (но я с ней в виндовской консоли не сталкивался)).

Соответственно текст, закодированный в программе надо перекодировать в зависимости от того, куда его выводите. Аналогично, надо перекодировать обмен между консолью и файлами (это если хотите, чтобы юзеру удобно было).

Для распознавания кодировки консоли я анализирую вывод popen("mkdir /","r"); Если винда английская, то ругается тоже не по русски, тогда беру по умолчанию cp-866, если иного не задано в environment LANG. Обычно в винде ее никто не устанавливает, поэтому она на последнем месте. В некоторых программах, в зависимости от вывода mkdir пишу сообщения или по русски или на (ломаном) английском.

Еще надо не забыть проверить (isatty()) stdin, stdout и stderr - это консоль или файлы и соответственно что куда надо перекодировать.

Успехов.